# WCF DataServiceProviderMethods.Compare() versus string.Compare()

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-data-services

It seems some queries generated by WCF Data Services will build expressions that call the following method (which might just be a stub):

DataServiceProviderMethods.Compare Method (String, String)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff452689.aspx

There was already the static string.Compare(string, string) plus various overloads.

Does anyone know why this new method was deemed justified?

Comment: In the documentation. This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

Comment: @Blam When implementing a LINQ backend (such as for NHibernate) for WCF Data Services, one must know about and handle expressions containing this method. Not an enormous problem, but it would be interesting to hear the reasoning for why string.Compare() wasn't good enough.

Answer (score 0):

The methods in the DataServiceProviderMethods class are not really intended to be called directly.  The method you are referring to is a placeholder method.  The dataServiceProviderMethods class is utilized in expression trees.  As the expression tree is generated if a node requires a comparison, the method in this class is referenced as a place holder in that node.  The actual provider is expected to parse through the expression tree and patch up these methods with their own methods.  By utilizing these unique methods it makes it possible to identify the methods that need to be patched within the expression tree by the provider.

Its a long read... but you will get a better understanding i think if you read this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg191846.aspx

(do a search for "Queries in the UnTyped\RO Sample" within that document if you want to skip a lot of the explanation)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen the explanations regarding GetValue() and some of the others. Problem is, every page I've found that talks about DataServiceProviderMethods speaks of GetValue() and three other methods (for which I understand the rationale), but mentions nothing about the set of Compare() methods.

Comment: The class documentation for DataServiceProviderMethods.Compare Method (String, String) does that the comparison is done by ordinal order. But string.Compare() has an overload for that so it stills seems funny.

Comment: Actually i see your point.  The compare method is actually implemented with:  'public static int Compare(String left, String right)
        {
            return Comparer<string>.Default.Compare(left, right);
        }'